# Xamarin Android DrawerLayout close onclick

Tags: android, xamarin, drawerlayout

I tried to implement a drawer layout with Xamarin following this example

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/DrawerSample

In my sliding menu I have 5 switch buttons (on/off) but when I click in the sliding menu it autotically close it. I can only open and close the menu, but I can't interract with my switch buttons.

Do you have any idea why the drawer layout close itself onclick ?

Comment: Is your main layout correctly ordered?

Comment: Thx a lot I put the content before the menu ! You re a genious ;)